# Creating a single page blog in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am hosting WordPress internally. I want to create a WordPress blog. I want the blog to be 1 page which shows all the recent posts and users can use the pagination to find old posts.

I go to settings and set the Home page to show the latest post and choose the Summary option.

[image]

Now the blog shows all of my articles in the home page, but it shows the full artciel... I want to  see a summary: https://blog.shopless.co.nz/

The other problem is that I don't know how to edit the Home page? When I open the pages, I cannot see Home page:

[image]

So I don't know how to open the home page to change it's format? For example I want the blog posts to be shown in 3 columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain about `Your homepage display` setting first.

1. You latest post - When you select this wordpress uses post archive template to show all your latest blogs. You cannot really edit it if you are not using page builder (eg. Elementor etc.). Other way to edit that area is to make changes to the theme. You can do that by creating a child theme. You can read about them here. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/. You will then be able to change the template.
2. A static page - This lets you chose your homepage and post page. Homepage is the one which open as `home_url()` and post page is the archive page where the posts are shown.

According to me you should opt for static page. You can do the following to set it up.

- Create a page and name it homepage.
- Go the reading setting and set static page - Hompage option to the page you created just now.
- Now if you visit your home url you can see the homepage, now the task is to add posts on the page.
- Go and edit the page, you would see a `+` button to add a new block.
  [image]
- Search for latest posts and add it to the page.
  [image]
- You can change the following

[image]
[image]
[image]

> These are the default blocks of wordpress, you can look for custom blogs on google if you want more customization, you will get free and premium options.

> You can also choose to edit the homepage using a page builder. Look for elementor free version to get started.